# Android: Download and install update APK without Google Play Store gives apk parse error

Tags: android, installation, filepath

I have an Android app that, for project requirements, cannot be put in stores. But I want that the restricted number of users of it can update the app when I fix bugs or I intriduce new features.
To do this, I use the AppUpdater library (https://github.com/javiersantos/AppUpdater), in order to check if a new version of the app is available, and I created a listener for the "update now" button, that triggers a DownloadManager with a ProgressBar, downloading the APK file in the smartphone, and then I use some code I found to try to install it automatically.
The download works fine, but when the installation code is executed, I receive this error: "Parse Error : There is a problem parsing the package". I already have "debug with USB" mode activated, "Unknown sources" too, and the APK is not corrupt.
Maybe I provide a wrong file path to the installation code? How to find the path correctly? Any other suggestion? Thanks! This is my code:

Manifest permissions:

```
<!-- Needs internet to connect to Google Services -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <!-- Permission to check internet connection state -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <!-- Keeps processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <!-- Permission to vibrate when receive a notification -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <!-- Lets app receive data messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <!-- Permission to set alarms again when device is rebooted -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <!-- Permission to disable the keylock -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
    <!-- Permission to write to external storage -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- Permission to read from external storage -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

AppUpdater library code (I put it in the MainActivity's onResume() method):

```
 // Check for app's updates with confirmation dialog
 AppUpdater appUpdater = new AppUpdater(this);

 appUpdater.setUpdateFrom(UpdateFrom.JSON)
           .setUpdateJSON(Constants.URL_UPDATE_JSON)
           .setDisplay(Display.DIALOG)
           .setButtonDoNotShowAgain(null)
           .setTitleOnUpdateAvailable("Available update")
           .setContentOnUpdateAvailable("Do you want to update the app?")
           .setButtonUpdate("Update now")
           .setButtonUpdateClickListener(new UpdateButtonClickListener(this))
           .setButtonDismiss("Later")
           .setIcon(R.mipmap.icon_icare)
           .showAppUpdated(false);

 appUpdater.start();
```

UpdateButtonClickListener:

```
public class UpdateButtonClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
    {
     Context context;

     ProgressDialog progressDialog;

     // Constructor
     public UpdateButtonClickListener(Context context)
        {
         this.context = context;
         this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        }


     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
        {
         progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading app");
         progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
         progressDialog.setMax(100);
         progressDialog.setProgressNumberFormat("");
         progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
         progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

         // Download APK file from server and install it
         DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile();
         downloadFile.execute();  
        }


     private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
        {
         @Override
         protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids)
            {
             Uri apk_uri = Uri.parse(Constants.URL_UPDATE_APK);

             DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(apk_uri);

             request.setTitle("Downloading app");
             request.setDescription("Please wait while downloading the updated app");

             request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, null, Constants.APK_NAME);

             // enqueue this request
             DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
             long downloadID = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

             boolean downloading = true;

             while(downloading)
                {
                 DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
                 q.setFilterById(downloadID);

                 Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(q);
                 cursor.moveToFirst();

                 int bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                 int bytes_total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));
                 if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL)
                    {
                     downloading = false;
                     progressDialog.dismiss();

                     // ---- IS THE PATH CORRECT? I WANT THE PATH OF THE FILE JUST DOWNLOADED
                     String localFilePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("local_uri"));

                     File apkFile = new File(localFilePath);

                     // ---- THIS IS THE INSTALLATION CODE
                     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                     intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apkFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                     context.startActivity(intent);
                    }

                 final int dl_progress = (int) ((bytes_downloaded * 100) / bytes_total);

                 progressDialog.setProgress(dl_progress);

                 //Toast.makeText(context, statusMessage(cursor), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 cursor.close();
                }

             return null;
            }


         private String statusMessage(Cursor c)
            {
             String msg;
             switch(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)))
                {
                 case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
                        msg = "Download failed!";
                        break;

                 case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
                        msg = "Download paused!";
                        break;

                 case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
                        msg = "Download pending!";
                        break;

                 case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
                        msg = "Download in progress!";
                        break;

                 case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
                        msg = "Download complete!";
                        break;

                 default:
                        msg = "Download is nowhere in sight";
                        break;
                }

             return msg;
            }


         @Override
         protected void onPreExecute()
            {
             super.onPreExecute();
             progressDialog.show();
            }


         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
            {    
             super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I'm almost there! As I thought, the error was an incorrect path to APK file. I substituted this line of code:

```
File apkFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), Constants.APK_NAME);
```

Now the installation starts correctly, but after some seconds it closes, as if some crash occurs, and the app doesn't get updated.

This is my Android Monitor log when the app closes while trying to install:

> 05-31 14:01:09.208 22383-28884/? W/System.err:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
>   com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri
>   content://media/external/fs_id from pid=17552, uid=10092 requires
>   android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
>   05-31 14:01:09.208 22383-28884/? W/System.err:     at
>   android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:605)
>   05-31 14:01:09.208 22383-28884/? W/System.err:     at
>   android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:480)
>   05-31 14:01:09.208 22383-28884/? W/System.err:     at
>   android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:211)
>   05-31 14:01:09.208 22383-28884/? W/System.err:     at
>   android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
>   05-31 14:01:09.208 22383-28884/? W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453) 05-31 14:01:09.208
>   22383-28884/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
>                                                     java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
>   com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri
>   content://media/external/fs_id from pid=17552, uid=10092 requires
>   android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
>                                                         at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:605)
>                                                         at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:480)
>                                                         at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:211)
>                                                         at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
>                                                         at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)

But my Manifest file already have this permission set, why this behavior?

Comment: are you sure that the APK is signed with the same certificate as the installed one?

Comment: @VladMatvienko, if I browse the filesystem with Android's file manager tool, if I click on the downloaded APK file it gets installed, so I suppose the problem is the code I use for installation.

Comment: May I know the version of OS of the phone you are testing it on.

Comment: Reason being Uri.fromFile(apkFile) will not work os OS version 7.0 and above.

Comment: @NitinMesta I'm using Android 6.0. I suppose the path to the file is wrong. However, how can I make it work in Android 7.0 too? Is there another method that works from Android 21 on?

Comment: please see file provider https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html . https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

Comment: @NitinMesta, how to integrate FileProvider with DownloadManager?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, since write to external storage is in dangerous permission list , even though you declare it in manifest , and if the user denied it you cannot do the operation requiring this permission . Please go through these links

Dangerous permission 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous

How to handle permission in marshmallow

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Also add this to you intent

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

which will temporarily grant the read permission to the app with which you are performing the operation.

Hope this helps

Comment: Even adding this line of code in my Intent, it doesn't work, I have the same error. What about performing operations in internal storage? Is it possible? And is it considered "less dangerous"?

Comment: Internal storage meaning app's data directory ?? Then the images will be private to the app and they may not appear to the other app. For this you don't need write permission as it will be local to your app and within apps own storage

Comment: can you please go to settings and check permission for storage for your app is granted or not

Comment: do you mean in Manifest file?

EDIT: Sorry, I got it! In my app's settings, under authorizations, the storage checkbox is unchecked

Comment: But even checking it I have the same error, it starts the installation and then creashes with that permission exception.

Comment: Check Android Monitor for the crash. Check which line of code you are getting this exception. something may be wrong their . Post your exception logs here.

Comment: I just edited my question with the Android monitor log.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145555/discussion-between-nitin-mesta-and-ciammarica).